# XCODE UserTracking with custom Marker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode13

I am learning iOS development I want to show userTracking mode to follow with customer marker. Below is how I have tried to create marker on map

```
 @IBOutlet weak var mapKIT: MKMapView!
@objc func labelAction(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        //Haptic Engine
        let impact = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator()
        impact.impactOccurred()
        
        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((latitude)!, (longitude)!)
        let regionSpant = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: regionDistance, longitudinalMeters: regionDistance)
        let placeMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)        
        mapKIT.isZoomEnabled = true
        
        mapKIT.setRegion(regionSpant, animated: true)
        mapKIT.layer.name = "You are here"
        if counter == 0{
            mapKIT.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
            counter = 1
        }
        if speeds! <= 0.9{
            mapKIT.addAnnotation(placeMark)
            mapKIT.userLocation.title = "You are here"
        }else{
            mapKIT.showsUserLocation = true
            mapKIT.userTrackingMode = .follow
        }
```

And down below is how am getting User Gps information.

```
var lastCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var latitude:CLLocationDegrees?
var longitude:CLLocationDegrees?
var muda:Date?
var speeds:Double?
    func locationManager(_ _manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations Location:[CLLocation]){
            if let location = Location.first{
                coordinate.text = "Your location \(location.coordinate.latitude.description) \(location.coordinate.longitude.description) - \(location.timestamp.description) "
                speed.text = "Your moving at speed of \(location.speed.description) course \(location.courseAccuracy.description)"
                altitude.text = "Your at altitude of \(location.altitude.description )"
                muda = location.timestamp
    
                latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
                longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
                muda = location.timestamp
                speeds = location.speed
                
            }
```

What I want is the marker I have create on map to move or to follow the moving direction in map.For now it's just create marker all over the place I have been.I apologies for my English I am using google translator